# Нижняя рамка активных элементов

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте, у меня при наведении на элемент в Google Chrome должна появляться рамка 3px, но сначала появляется однопиксельная, и потом достраивается до 3px, выглядит некрасиво очень, в других браузерах такой проблемы нет. Помогите пожалуйста, первый раз такое.

```css
#reg_auth>a:hover {
  color: #dfdfdf;
  border-bottom: 3px solid silver;
}
```

```html
<div id="reg_auth">
  <a href="" title="Войти в кабинет пользователя">Войти</a>
  <a href="" title="Зарегистрироваться на сайте">Регистрация</a>
</div>
```

Comment: @Yuri, а смысл от сниппета, если всё равно не воспроизводится?

Comment: @Qwertiy, hover то работает :)

Comment: @Yuri, но граница сразу 3px, она не увеличивается от 1 до 3.

Comment: @Qwertiy, ну это да. Надо бы GIF загрузить или картинку, на которой видно проблему

Comment: Все норм сатло после добавления transparent, вообще не знаю с чем связано было,Спасибо большое!!!я еще не научился сайтом пользоваться просто

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
#reg_auth > a:hover{
  color: #dfdfdf;
  border-bottom: 3px solid silver;
}

a, a:link, a:visited, a:hover, a:active, a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="reg_auth">
  <a href="" title="Войти в кабинет пользователя">Войти</a>
  <a href="" title="Зарегистрироваться на сайте">Регистрация</a>
</div>
```

```css
#reg_auth > a:hover{
  color: #dfdfdf;
  border-bottom-color: silver;
}

a {
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
}

a, a:link, a:visited, a:hover, a:active, a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="reg_auth">
  <a href="" title="Войти в кабинет пользователя">Войти</a>
  <a href="" title="Зарегистрироваться на сайте">Регистрация</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, если вы не заняты, перейдите в чат: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52027/communication-with-the-yuri . Я хотел бы спросить у вас совет

Comment: Этот код есть, но все равно в  chrome не работает, в других браузерах нормально все, в чем еще может быть проблема?Извините еще раз!

Comment: @D.Semenov, у меня хром и у меня всё работает.

Comment: @D.Semenov, добавил ещё вариант.

Comment: а как в чате писать?,я даун

Comment: @D.Semenov, кажется никак, если только система не предложит сама чат создать на основе комментариев. Тебе репутации не хватает.

Comment: Кстати, я рекомендую оставить в базе знаний только второй вариант, поскольку для новичка использовать первый — означает возникновение вопроса "а почему оно дергается при наведении и как это исправить?"